# Selenium: driver.actions(...).moveToElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Hi I've created all my tests using Selenium IDE and have now started to export them to JavaScript Mocha to have them running in travis.

The tests run fine in selenium ide and I can export them, but when I run it it says "TypeError: driver.actions(...).moveToElement is not a function".

```js
 it('Console Page should work', async function() {
    await driver.get("https://myurl.com/")
    await driver.manage().window().setRect(1536, 824)
    await driver.findElement(By.id("loginLink")).click()
    {
      const element = await driver.findElement(By.id("Password"))
      await driver.actions({ bridge: true }).moveToElement(element).clickAndHold().perform() // this line fails
    }
```

package dependancies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^7.1.2",
    "chromedriver": "^81.0.4044.138",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.7"
  }
```

Comment: Same error. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
await driver.actions({bridge:true}).moveToElement(element).clickAndHold().perform()
```

To

```
await driver.actions({ bridge:true}).move(element).clickAndHold().perform()
```

It's change from new versions

Answer (score 2):

Below is a comparison between how it is working in **Python**, **Java** and **JavaScript**:

Python:

```
# Performs mouse move action onto the element
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(yourElement).perform()
```

Java:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
// Performs mouse move action onto the element
actions.moveToElement(yourElement).build().perform();
```

JavaScript:

```
const actions = await driver.actions({bridge: true});
// Performs mouse move action onto the element
await actions.move({duration: 1000, origin:yourElement, x: 1, y: 1}).perform();
```

Comment: The _JavaScript_ code here doesn't work. It will result in `actions` not being a function. Perhaps the second part should just be: `actions.move`...?